# SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) - Catch User-Stopped Debugging

Tags: ssis

For a custom audit framework that I am implementing in a SQL Server SSIS solution, I need to log when debugging stops.

As far as I can tell, there are 3 possible situations:
1. An error is occured that is fatal (i.e. it is not ignored or allowed to occur to then be handled separately).
2. Execution finishes succesfully.
3. Debugging stops due to a crash or user stopping (i.e. the STOP button, shift + f5).

1 and 2 I can handle with an event handler and task respectively. However, I can't seem to find an event that is triggered when debugging stops due to user cancelling or system shut down (these are possibly 2 separate categories).

Can anyone advise how I can catch these or process them at a later stage.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Why are you trying to log development events?  Logging is intended for capturing execution events of your finished code.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding you but when an ETL process fails due to a user stopping execution, it is just as important that this is logged as anything that else that causes an ETL process to fail. I am creating a auditing framework so I know exactly what is in the database, via which package, from which data source etc. I appreciate this wouldn't be relevant in a live production environment but due to various constraints outside of my control, my current environment is a forever-development environment.

Comment: If you want to monitor Dev, that's fine, but it should be done as in production.  Run the package via dtexec.exe or similar means and use normal logging.  You should not need to monitor debugging because that is strictly part of the development process.  I have supported testing in dev in a similar fashion, you can run the ETL via sql agent.  But what happens in development is just noise.  You should be concerned with the code that people finally check in and promote.

Answer (score 2):

You could try hooking the [OnQueryCancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140223.aspx) event. As the docs state

> The event handler for the OnQueryCancel event. This event is raised by an executable to determine whether it should stop running.

Where this gets fun (and tricky) is that the OnQueryCancel event is raised throughout the package execution. Basically, it's taking a breath before putting its face back in the water. So, you'll need to check whether the system Variable `Cancel`, which only exists in the `OnQueryCancel` event handler scope, is set to true.

In my POC, I set the expression on the `Disabled` property for my Script Task to be `!@[System::Cancel]` and that seemed to work fine. It stopped displaying my message box when I hadn't clicked Cancel. Unfortunately, it also didn't *show* the message box when I did click "Stop Debugging"

I need to wrap up for the day and will revisit this tonight but thought I'd leave you with the beginning of an answer which hopefully shoves you in the right direction

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d7ad9d7-9889-4b1d-859b-8fa6d281e63f/what-does-the-onquerycancel-event-do

Comment: Hi, thanks for this preliminary answer. It gives me something to think about but I'm a little unclear on exactly what you mean. Are you able to rephrase? Are you saying the OnQueryCancel event will capture a "cancelled task" if the task's disabled property points at the system cancel variable? Would this mean I would have to modify every single task's disabled property to point to this var? Also, are you saying it causes message boxes as popped up by script tasks to fail? Thanks in advance, I appreciate your time.