# Custom logging in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have created a process log table which has a field called execution status, this field should be populated with success when package has completed successfully, failure when package has failed, running when package is running and terminated when package is terminated by user.

I'm able to populate the first three values but I am facing issues to implement the terminated value in the table.

I have used event handler on error to get failed status and rest values are populated in control flow itself.

Help me to implement the terminated value.

Comment: What version of SSIS is this?

Comment: Probably no way to capture that unless you're running it via the SSISDB. Even then, it'd be a backfill process versus adding an Execute SQL Task to your packages. Quasi related Q http://stackoverflow.com/q/26136824/181965

Answer (score 0):

'Termination' happens outside of the package execution process and may be caused not only by 'User'. It can happen on every level including lack of AC/DC power. Usually package is already not working (not responding before end of defined timeout or user patience).

My solution was to calculate additional status like 'running too long' for situation when logged status is 'running' and difference between its StartDate and Now() is higher than it should be (either from business point of view or from previous observations).

*Posted as an answer instead of a comment because I was unable to leave a comment.*